# Looking to loop over difference numpy array slicings

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I have a multi dimensional numpy array where i am looking to take different slicings from like this:

```
A=Array[1,:,:,:,:]
B=Array[:,1,:,:,:]
C=Array[:,:,1,:,:]
D=Array[:,:,:,1,:]
E=Array[:,:,:,:,1]
```

I then need to process these in the exact same way so i thought about doing it in a simple loop.
However i do not know how to do this.

I thought about list comprehension like:

```
for i in range(5):
   Sliced=Array[1 if x==i else : for x in range(5)]
```

but this obviously does not work.

Comment: Look at `np.take`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `Array[x,y,z]` you are actually passing a tuple `(x,y,z)` into the brackets `[...]`, while `a:b:c` constructs within there are syntax sugar for `slice(a, b, c)` with `None` in place of unspecified values (e.g. `::2` is `slice(None, None, 2)`). So what you mean should be obtained with something like this:

```
for i in range(5):
    Sliced = Array[tuple(1 if x==i else slice(None) for x in range(5))]
```

Comment: Thank you, this exactly what i needed. Actually found out about slice objects right after posting this but did not realize i could also put everything into a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, one way would be to rotate the axis of array instead of index:

```
arr = np.random.random((2,3,4,5,6))

arrays = []
for i in range(arr.ndim):
    print(arr.shape)
    arrays.append(arr[1, ...])
    arr = np.moveaxis(arr, 0, -1)
```

Output for shape:

```
(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
(3, 4, 5, 6, 2)
(4, 5, 6, 2, 3)
(5, 6, 2, 3, 4)
(6, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```